# How can I change the targets of a large collection of symlinks efficiently?

Tags: bash, symlink, batch-rename

So, I have a collection of about a thousand symlinks from one Linux directory into a sibling directory that are used to reorganize a bunch of files without copying them.

Here is a simulation of my situation with 3 files:

```
$ ls ref reorg -l
ref:
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 me 0 28 fév 11:57 a-foo.txt
-rw-r----- 1 me 0 28 fév 11:57 b-bar.txt
-rw-r----- 1 me 0 28 fév 11:57 c-baz.txt

reorg:
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me   16 28 fév 11:58 a.txt -> ../ref/a-foo.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me   16 28 fév 11:58 b.txt -> ../ref/b-bar.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me   16 28 fév 11:58 c.txt -> ../ref/c-baz.txt
```

Now, I realized I should have created a deeper structure, so what I really want is this:

```
$ ls reorg/subdir/ -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me 19 28 fév 12:04 a.txt -> ../../ref/a-foo.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me 19 28 fév 12:04 b.txt -> ../../ref/b-bar.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me 19 28 fév 12:04 c.txt -> ../../ref/c-baz.txt
```

Using `cp -a reorg/*.txt reorg/subdir` or `mv reorg/*.txt reorg/subdir` will yield a bunch of broken symlinks, since they will be missing the extra `../`. And recreating the symlinks from scratch will be a lot of work due to the amount of reorganizing encoded in these symlinks.

Does anyone know of a solution like `rename`, but which would systematically change my thousand symlink targets?

The obvious solution (and probably what I will do) is to write a bash script like this:

```
mv reorg/*.txt reorg/subdir
for l in reorg/subdir/*.txt; do
   newtarget=`readlink $l | sed 's/^/..\//'`
   ln -sf $newtarget $l
done
```

and this works, I tested, but I was hoping for a more direct solution, similar to `rename`, so I don't have to write such a script each time I face the problem. I work with symlinks a lot, so this problem will come up again.

This would be my ideal solution, if it existed (using the CentOS rename-like syntax, not the Ubuntu one, but either would be good):

```
mv reorg/*.txt reorg/subdir
rename-link-targets ../ ../../ reorg/subdir/*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: No, I don't know of a symlink editor like you describe.

And now, a hack:

```
cd reorg
ln -s ../ref .
```

I get that you don't want to have to re-do the for loop everytime, but your `for` loop to edit thousands of links could just as well be a for loop to re-create thousands of links, couldn't it?

```
rm -rf reorg
mkdir reorg/subdir
cd reorg/subdir
for f in ../../ref/*.txt; do
   ln -s $f .
done
cd ../..
```

And lastly, focusing on the "each time I face this problem" part, consider using an absolute path in your symlink.  Then you can move reorg/subdir anywhere you want, and the paths still work:

```
rm -rf reorg
mkdir reorg/subdir
cd reorg/subdir
for f in /absolute/path/to/ref/*.txt; do
   ln -s $f .
done
cd ../..
```

If that still isn't palatable, I'll go back to the hack:

- have your text files in a known directory (ref)
- create /path/to/sym-dir that is a symlink to that directory (ref)
- create symlinks in reorg/subdir that link to specific files in /path/to/sym-dir

Now you can move reorg/subdir anywhere you want to, because those symlinks use absolute paths.  And, you can move ref anywhere you want to, so long as you then
blow away /path/to/sym-dir and re-create it.

Sure, fopen will grumble at you for having to go through two levels of indirection, but that may be the price that has to be paid.

HTH.

Comment: There's a subtlety I included in the setup but didn't explicitly say, sorry: the links don't have the same names as the refs (a.txt -> a-foo.txt) and in my real case, the refs are in a complex directory structure and reorg is in a different, less complex but still not flat, directory structure. Absolute paths would certainly work, although they make the whole structure non-movable later. The hack is probably the best idea, and I don't mind a bit having fopen grumbling at me. :) (Well, maybe I will mind when things are slow, but I doubt I'll notice...)

Comment: PS: still hoping for a direct `rename-link-targets` command. I might have to write it myself...